# Constraints with condition in CVXPY

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I want to add constraints like this:

```py
constraint = cp.sum(cp.multiply(x, a)) > 10 if x*a != 0
```

where `x` is decision variable and a is constant. I know `if` condition and chain constraints are not allowed. But how can I implement this condition?

I also report a issue for csxpy in [github](https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/issues/2006).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be implemented linearly by considering `y=a*x` to be **semi-continuous**.

```
 y = a*x
 10*δ ≤ y ≤ 9999*δ
 δ ∈ {0,1}
```